# Netlify Redirect Gatsby Path to React App with Status Code 200 but keep getting White Screen

Tags: reactjs, netlify

I've got a portfolio called `example.com` and a small app, both hosted on netlify independently of each other - but I want the app accessable under the same domain my portfolio is on.

So I want to redirect the path `/sandwich-maker` to my app `https://sandwich-example-4bbo00.netlify.app` so that the site is accessable at `example.com/sandwichmaker`. All while people can still see my portfolio at `example.com`.

My first attempt was creating a `_redirects` file and forcefully redirecting it.

```
/sandwich-maker   https://sandwich-example-4bbo00.netlify.app 200!
```

My second attempt was using the `netlify.toml` feature and using a redirect.

```
[[redirects]]
  from = "/sandwich-maker"
  to = "https://sandwich-example-4bbo00.netlify.app"
  status = 200
  force = true
  headers = {X-From = "Netlify"}
```

I've been able to get redirects to work between two past-project gatsby sites but not between a gatsby site and a react app.

When I try to access the app I just keep getting a white screen and if I inspect the `body` it says "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.".

I've tried forcefully redirecting and not, nothing seems to work. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Finally found a workaround for it!*

The solution I found was to use the `<base>` tag in my React application.

```html
<head>
    <base href="https://sandwich-example-4bbo00.netlify.app/">
    ...
</head>
```

The issue was that relatively referenced resources didn't exist on the main domain, so setting the context with `<base>` should fix all the missing files.